# Steps on how to set up Sonarqube for Xcode/Swif Project

Tags: swift, sonarqube, xcode13, sonarscanner

I have been trying to get this done for two days now. I have had different error to deal with. I am Using an M1 Apple Chip Mac pro and Xcode 13.4 and it has been difficult to get Sonarqube running. I finally found a docker image which is M1 specific and I have been able to get Sonarqube running locally.

My current challenge is having the test result sent to the Sonarqube project.
I have tried several method which includes
`xcrun xccov view YourPathToThisFile/*.xccovreport --json`
This script is not working even though I wanted an xml format.

Is there a better way to have the code coverage report sent to sonarqube. I have Sonarqube running but the test result and coverage is not showing. Sonarqube page currently says "The main branch has no lines of code."

NB: I am running Sonarqube with Docker

Below is my Sonarqube properties file.

```
#
# Swift SonarQube Plugin - Enables analysis of Swift and Objective-C projects into SonarQube.
# Copyright © 2015 Backelite (${email})
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

# Sonar Server details
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/
sonar.login=782a04fee8bfc7ae181f04bbd13734eb89e5580c

# sonar.password=admin

# Project Details
sonar.projectKey=tinggios
sonar.projectName=TinggIOSApp
sonar.projectDescription=This is TinggiOS

# Comment if you have a project with mixed ObjC / Swift
sonar.language=swift
sonar.projectKey=tinggios
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true

# Path to source directories
# sonar.sources=SonarDemo,SonarDemoTests,SonarDemoUITests
sonar.sources=.

# Exclude directories
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
sonar.test.inclusions=*.swift
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*
# sonar.inclusions=*.swift

# Path to test directories (comment if no test)
sonar.tests=TinggIOS/Core/Tests/CoreTests,TinggIOS/Home/Tests/HomeTests,TinggIOS/OnboardingUITest

# Destination Simulator to run surefire
# As string expected in destination argument of xcodebuild command
# Example = sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.2
# sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.0
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=15

# Xcode project configuration (.xcodeproj)
# and use the later to specify which project(s) to include in the analysis (comma separated list)
# Specify either xcodeproj or xcodeproj + xcworkspace
sonar.swift.project=TinggIOS/TinggIOS.xcodeproj
sonar.swift.workspace=TinggIOS/TinggIOS.xcworkspace

sonar.language=swift

sonar.c.file.suffixes=-
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=-
sonar.objc.file.suffixes=-
# Specify your appname.
# This will be something like "myApp"
# Use when basename is different from targeted scheme.
# Or when slather fails with 'No product binary found'
sonar.swift.appName=TinggIOS

# Scheme to build your application
sonar.swift.appScheme=TinggIOS

# Configuration to use for your scheme. if you do not specify that the default will be Debug
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug

##########################
# Optional configuration #
##########################

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# SCM
# sonar.scm.enabled=true
# sonar.scm.url=scm:git:http://xxx

# JUnit report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
# The XML files have to be prefixed by TEST- otherwise they are not processed
sonar.junit.reportsPath=sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml

# Cobertura report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/coverage-swift.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/coverage-swift*.xml
#sonar.coverageReportPaths=sonarqube-generic-coverage.xml
#sonar.swift.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/cobertura.xml

# OCLint report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/oclint.xml
# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.swiftlint.report=sonar-reports/*swiftlint.txt

# Change it only if you generate the file on your own
sonar.swift.tailor.report=sonar-reports/*tailor.txt

# Paths to exclude from coverage report (surefire, 3rd party libraries etc.)
# sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=pattern1,pattern2
# sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage=.*Tests.*,

##########################
# Tailor configuration #
##########################
# Tailor configuration
# -l,--max-line-length=<0-999>                  maximum Line length (in characters)
#    --list-files                               display Swift source files to be analyzed
#    --max-class-length=<0-999>                 maximum Class length (in lines)
#    --max-closure-length=<0-999>               maximum Closure length (in lines)
#    --max-file-length=<0-999>                  maximum File length (in lines)
#    --max-function-length=<0-999>              maximum Function length (in lines)
#    --max-name-length=<0-999>                  maximum Identifier name length (in characters)
#    --max-severity=<error|warning (default)>   maximum severity
#    --max-struct-length=<0-999>                maximum Struct length (in lines)
#    --min-name-length=<1-999>                  minimum Identifier name length (in characters)

sonar.swift.tailor.config=--no-color --max-line-length=100 --max-file-length=500 --max-name-length=40 --max-name-length=40 --min-name-length=4
```